# Cannot access property on Swift type from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, types, objective-c-swift-bridge

I am trying to access a Swift class's `Double?` property from Objective-C.

```swift
class BusinessDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var lat : Double?
    var lon : Double?

    // Other elements...
}
```

In another view controller, I am trying to access `lat` like following:

```objectivec
#import "i5km-Swift.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) BusinessDetailViewController *businessDetailViewController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.businessDetailViewController = [[BusinessDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BusinessDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.businessDetailViewController.lat = businessArray[1]; /* THIS GIVES ME AN ERROR */
}
```

and I am getting

> Property 'lat' not found on object of type 'BusinessDetailViewController *'

Why can't I access this property? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know because in businessDetailViewController, I also have an outlet `@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView?` and I can access it from outside but it does not have `public`

Comment: I think optional structs are not visible in Objective-C.  Will validate.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Optional values of non-Objective-C types aren't bridged into Objective-C. That is, the first three properties of `TestClass` below *would* be available in Objective-C, but the fourth wouldn't:

```
class TestClass: NSObject {
    var nsNumberVar: NSNumber = 0      // obj-c type, ok
    var nsNumberOpt: NSNumber?         // optional obj-c type, ok
    var doubleVar: Double = 0          // bridged Swift-native type, ok
    var doubleOpt: Double?             // not bridged, inaccessible
}
```

In your Objective-C code, you'd access those first three properties like this:

```
TestClass *optTest = [[TestClass alloc] init];
optTest.nsNumberOpt = @1.0;
optTest.nsNumberVar = @2.0;
optTest.doubleVar = 3.0;
```

In your case, you can either convert `lat` and `long` to be non-Optional or switch them to be instances of `NSNumber`.

---

Note that you need to be careful about your Objective-C code if you take the second approach (switching `lat` and `lon` to non-optional properties of type `NSNumber`) -- while the Swift compiler will prevent you from assigning `nil` to non-optional properties, the Objective-C compiler has no qualms about allowing it, letting `nil` values sneak into your Swift code with no chance of catching them at runtime. Consider this method on `TestClass`:

```
extension TestClass {
    func badIdea() {
        // print the string value if it exists, or 'nil' otherwise
        println(nsNumberOpt?.stringValue ?? "nil")

        // non-optional: must have a value, right?
        println(nsNumberVar.stringValue)
    }
}
```

This works fine if invoked with values in both of the properties, but if `nsNumberVar` is set to `nil` from the Objective-C code, this will crash at runtime. Note that there is *no way to check* whether or not `nsNumberVar` is `nil` before using it!

```
TestClass *optTest = [[TestClass alloc] init];
optTest.nsNumberOpt = @1.0;
optTest.nsNumberVar = @2.0;
[optTest badIdea];
// prints 1, 2

optTest.nsNumberOpt = nil;
optTest.nsNumberVar = nil;
[optTest badIdea];
// prints nil, then crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception
```

Comment: I couldn't track it down in the docs but the compiler will tell you it's not representable with `@objc protocol FooProtocol { var lat:Double? {get} }`

Comment: The documentation on this is patchy - for example, [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html) says that enumerations and structures defined in Swift aren't available in Obj-C, but doesn't mention that Optionals (which are implemented as an `enum`) and most of the built `struct` types bridge properly until you get to [the page on Cocoa data types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_41).

Comment: @NateCook I cannot prove it, but I think an optional `NSNumber` is bridged and an optional `Int` or `Float` isn't is because `NSNumber` is a reference type, and `.None` is mapped to `nil`, whereas a value type doesn't have a `nil` counterpart in objc. I'm not correcting you, just wondering if you agree

Comment: @Antonio: That's right - in Objective-C any reference type can be `nil`, so they're automatically bridged to Swift optionals. In fact, one could argue that in a bridged project, no reference types should ever be non-Optional, since you can assign `nil` to even a non-Optional property from Objective-C, leading to potential crashes with no recourse. See my addition...

Comment: Good to know - don't use bridging at objc side, but it's something to keep in mind when I will (it's just a matter of time for that to happen :))

Answer (score 15):

If your property is a Swift protocol type, just add `@objc` in front of it.

Example:

```
class Foo: UIViewController {
   var delegate: FooDelegate?
   ...
}

@objc protocol FooDelegate {
   func bar()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Optionals is a swift specific feature, not available in obj-c. Optional class instances work because a nil optional can be mapped to a nil value, but value types (int, floats, etc.) are **not** reference types, hence variable of those types don't store a reference, but the value itself.

I don't know if there's a solution - a possible workaround is creating non optional properties mapping the `nil` value to an unused data type value (such as -1 when representing an index, or 999999 for a coordinate):

```
class Test {
    var lat : Double? {
        didSet {
            self._lat = self.lat != nil ? self.lat! : 999999
        }
    }
    var lon : Double? {
        didSet {
            self._lon = self.lon != nil ? self.lon! : 999999
        }
    }

    var _lat: Double = 99999999
    var _lon: Double = 99999999
}
```

That should expose the `_lat` and `_lon` properties to obj-c.

Note that I have never tried that, so please let us know if it works.

Comment: just give it a try and yes, we can access _lat and _lon from outside. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> [`UInt?` `Int?` or `Double?` properties] cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C.

It is, however, possible to "wrap" them in a NSNumber like so :

```
class Foo {
    var bar: Double?
}

// MARK: Objective-C Support
extension Foo {
    /// bar is `Double?` in Swift and `(NSNumber * _Nullable)` in Objective-C
    @objc(bar)
    var z_objc_bar: NSNumber? {
        get {
            return bar as NSNumber?
        }
        set(value) {
            bar = value?.doubleValue ?? nil
        }
    }
}
```