# Cannot access Swift var from Objective-C View controller - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, properties, var

I have an app with both Objective-C and Swift based view controllers. I am programatically opening a Swift based view controller from one of my Objective-C based view controllers. The problem I am having is that I can't access the Swift variables from my Objective-C code.

My Swift code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var profPicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var profVerified: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var profName: UILabel!
var passedUser:PFUser!
```

My Objective-C code:

```
MyProfileViewController *screen = [[MyProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.dataPass = screen;
dataPass.profName.text = @"";
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am able to access @ properties like IBOutlets, but I can't access and edit the var objects.

I am doing this, because I want to pass data into the Swift based view controller from the Objective-C based view controller when I am presenting the Swift based view controller.

Why can't I access the var objects?

Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

The error is as follows:

> Property 'passedUser' not found on object of type
>   'MyProfileViewController *'

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: On which line are you getting an error? What is the error message?

Comment: @Sulthan I updated my question.

Comment: You did not declare them `public`.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Tried that now, and it still comes up with the same error.

Comment: Look at this answer. According to that, if I understood it right, initializing the property (with nil?) and making them optional might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366082/cannot-access-property-of-swift-type-from-objective-c

Comment: @Sulthan Please repost your original answer, it the end it DID work, I was just having some Xcode cache issues. So I cleaned Xcode and my project and tried your answer again and it worked!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to declare the variable as `public`.

By default, the variables have `internal` access, that means they can be accessed only from inside their module. Obj-C code is not in their module.

Answer (score 25):

Swift 4:

Use **@objc** keyword to access the swift variable.

```
class Car: NSObject {
    @objc let name: String
    @objc let numberOfWheels: Int
    let manufacturer: String
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue with an ObjectiveC enum, that was a variable in a Swift class and wasn't accessible in ObjectiveC.

Declaring the variable as public didn't work, instead I had to give the enum a default value when declaring it, for it to be included in the [project]-Swift.h header.

```
 var firstQuestion: AnswerResult = AnswerNone
```

The following didn't work:

```
var firstQuestion: AnswerResult!
```

Answer (score 1):

With these all answers, sometimes compiler doesn't generate appropriate obj-c code for our swift code. In that case,

**Just clean & build project.**

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `@objc public` for the variable to expose it to Objective-C:

```
@IBOutlet @objc public weak var profName: UILabel!
```