# Swift 4.2 responds to Selector returns false, how to check if property exists?

Tags: swift, swift4.2

In the following example I expect the `x.responds(to: Selector(name))` to return true. However it doesn't.

`x.value(forKeyPath: name)` throws a `signal SIGABRT` error.

The same code worked in Swift 3.

My question: how do I check for properties in a class (that extends from NSObject) and retrieve them based on a string.

```
import UIKit

class Test: NSObject {
    var test = "test"
}

func property(_ object: Any, _ name: String) -> Bool? {
    let x = object as? NSObject

//    x?.value(forKeyPath: name)

    return x?.responds(to: Selector(name))
}

property(Test(), "test")
```

(code for a playground in Swift 4.2)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30795117/1187415 – `@objc var ...`

Comment: Possibly Related (?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479301/cannot-access-swift-var-from-objective-c-view-controller-ios

Comment: Can you just use native [`Swift 4` `KeyPath`s](https://www.klundberg.com/blog/swift-4-keypaths-and-you/)?

Comment: Thanks @user28434 didn't know about KeyPaths, might use it in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Placing `@objc` in front of `var test` fixed the issues.

```
import UIKit

class Test: NSObject {
    @objc var test = "test"
}

func property(_ object: Any, _ name: String) -> Bool? {
    let x = object as? NSObject

    x?.value(forKeyPath: name)

    return x?.responds(to: Selector(name))
}

property(Test(), "test")
```