# Some Swift class properties are not found when accessed from Objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to bring some Swift code into my older obj-c project. Swift class is accessible from obj-c class, but not all of it's properties though. For example

```
public var menuTitleColor: UIColor!
```

works perfectly fine, but

```
public var cellHeight: CGFloat!
```

is not found. I think it's because CGFloat is not an object. Is there a way to access this property without changing Swift file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Primitive types in Objective-C

Look at this Swift class

```
@objc class Foo: NSObject {
    var myCGFloatOptional: CGFloat? = 1
    var myCGFloat: CGFloat = 1
}
```

If I use it in Objective-C only the `myCGFloat` property is available.

```
Foo * foo = [Foo new];
foo.myCGFloat;
foo.myCGFloatOptional; // Compile Error
```

This because in Objective-C `CGFloat` is a primitive type (like `float`). And Objective-C does not allow `nil` values for a primitive type.

Just like you cannot write this in Objective-C

```
float number = 1;
number = nil; // compile error
```

### References to instances of classes

In your Objective-C code you are able to see a property of type `UIColor!` declared in Swift because `UIColor` is a class. So you are declaring a pointer that could reference an instance of `UIColor` or nothing.

And in Objective-C the same concept does exist.

### Note

You could note that `int` is a primitive type as well in Objective-C but, "unexpectedly", the compiler does allow you to write

```
int number = 1;
number = nil;
```

However in this case `nil` is simply interpreted as the integer 0 (still a value, not really `nil`).

Comment: Great explanation, thanks a lot! I accepted your answer instead of the first one, since it provides a lot more info on the subject and will be a lot more useful to anyone stumbling upon same issue.

Comment: Simple and easily understandable

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

`public var cellHeight: CGFloat = 0 //(or some other number)`

Comment: I never bridged Swift stuff to ObjC but it might have something to do with the property being a primitive value type. And it is unable to treat it as a force unwrapped reference type.

Comment: Primitives can't be nil in ObjC, so optional primitive properties are not imported. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26366289/72176 for a more detailed discussion.