# Stored properties in swift cannot be converted to properties in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I encountered a problem when access swift class in objective-c, stored properties in swift cannot be converted to properties in objective-c， such as:

```
var maxFixedWidth:Float? = defaultMaxWidth {
    didSet{
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}

var itemSpace:Float? = 4 {
    didSet{
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}
```

These cannot be converted to the following objective-c style properties that should be contained in `#import "JDStock-swift.h"`,

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat maxFixedWidth;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat itemSpace;
```

It puzzled me for a long time, appreciate for your answers, waiting for you all the time with patient, Thanks!

Comment: Why are your properties optional when you're giving them a default value? Do you need to be able to assign nil to them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access property of Swift type from Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366082/cannot-access-property-of-swift-type-from-objective-c)