# What's wrong with my code? Method cannot be an @objc

Tags: swift

What's wrong with my code? I keep getting this error, I don't know why it says method cannot be an @objc override because the type of parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MovieViewController
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        let item = TableData[indexPath.row]
        vc.senddMovie = item
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line you're getting this error

Comment: At line 1 on the override func prepare

Comment: Where did you place `@objc` on your above class ?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I can find the message _**because the type of parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C**_ only in Swift 2.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? In 8.2.1, `segue.destinationViewController` is now `segue.destination` so I suspect you're using an old version.

Comment: Im using xcode beta

Comment: Which version of Xcode beta? There's been a beta of almost every version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

it's because of the "Any?" in the function signature. it is a swift only type and can not be bridged to Objective-C.

see this answer discussing the issue :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26366289/4264079