# Swift - setValuesForKeys(dictionary) error - this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm new in Swift, and i have an issue with error **this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key**.

I have reread all related topics and did not find a solution to this problem.

Please check out the code and give me some advice, what have I done wrong?

```
class FriendScore: NSObject {
var name:String?
var highestScore:Int?
}

var allScoresArr = [FriendScore]()
var dataArr = [[String:Any]]()

dataArr =[["name": "Ben", "highestScore": 15],["name": "Alex", "highestScore": 12]]

for user in dataArray {

if let dictionary = user as? [String:Any] {
                        let friendScore = FriendScore()

                        //Error Happens Here "Thread Breakpoint"
                        friendScore.setValuesForKeys(dictionary) 
                        allScoresArr.append(friendScore)
                    }
 }

 print(allScoresArr)
```

The error:

```
<__lldb_expr_73.FriendScore 0x608000266080> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key highestScore.

'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366082/cannot-access-property-of-swift-type-from-objective-c: `Int?` is not representable in Objective-C. Make it an `Int` or an `NSNumber?`

Comment: @Martin R  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I hit this too.. Unfortunately the “lessoned learned” is that Swift is not nearly as flexible and powerful as Objective-C

this is a no-brainer in the native language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your example has a number of errors. First, you define `var dataArr`, then redefine `let dataArr`, then actually iterate over `dataArray`.

That aside, your dataArr is an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary is of type `[String: Any]`. When you call `setValuesForKeys(dictionary)`, it is attempting to set the value for `name` and `highestScore` to the values in the dictionary. Each of those values is of type `Any`, but what the `FriendScore` class expects is a value of type `String` for `name`, and a value of type `Int` for `highestScore`. You will need to cast each of the values to the correct type:

```
class FriendScore: NSObject {
    var name:String?
    var highestScore:Int?
}

let dataArr = [["name": "Ben", "highestScore": 15],["name": "Alex", "highestScore": 12]]

for user in dataArr {
    let friendScore = FriendScore()
    friendScore.name = user["name"] as? String
    friendScore.highestScore = user["highestScore"] as? Int
}
```

If your class had several parameters of the same type, you could simply use `setValuesForKeys` and pass a dictionary with an explicit type other than `Any`.

Comment: "var dataArr, then redefine let dataArr" - this is just an error in the example, typo, i missspell it unfortunatly. The key problem was in Friendscore class, Martin R already helped me.
But anyway, @drootang Thanks for the analysis and for your advices and comments. I appreciate it!